# Ubuntu upgrade from to 18.04.1 LTS stuck

Tags: upgrade

As said in the title, I started an upgrade of my system to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. The update has been stuck to this step for hours now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VatRe.jpg

It's worth noting that I had this error a bit before the update getting stuck : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUbpi.jpg

Does anyone here have a solution to that without screwing up all my system ?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, figured it out.

I first killed the upgrade with a `kill -9` command. It then appeared that my PC incorrectly waked up from sleep. I used `ps aux | grep suspend` to find a suspend process owned by root and killed it. I was then able to use `dpkg --configure -a`, `apt-get install -f`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get autoclean` and reboot safely. Note that the commands aren't necessarly in the right order, I don't remember exactly in which order did I do this.

After the reboot, used `apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing` and `apt-get dist-upgrade --fix broken` followed by a last `apt-get autoremove` and everything was fixed.